# Invoking a parameterless constructor of an interface

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

The other day I got a task to export some data into excel and the first thing that I looked at was `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library, I don't know that may not be the best way to do that but anyway, what got me in a twist was the fact that I had to make an instance of an `interface`. Yeah you can have some object's reference as an `interface` if it implements the corresponding one, but I am not talking about that. Basically this is the line of code I am talking about.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aa = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

pretty much this is just a regular object instantiation and there would be nothing special about this if `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` was not an `interface`. Now, first thing what you learn about interfaces when you are still in your early ages of education is that, you cannot make instance of an `interface`. but this proves that it's wrong. Well, not exactly, because this is the IL it generates behind it

```
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"
  IL_0006:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Guid::.ctor(string)
  IL_000b:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::GetTypeFromCLSID(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid)
  IL_0010:  call       object [mscorlib]System.Activator::CreateInstance(class [mscorlib]System.Type)
  IL_0015:  castclass  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
```

Now here, there is nothing that says "make an instance of an interface" (As I guess), so it's doing something behind that `interface` constructor. But still my question remains. How is it possible to use that kind of syntax with `interface` and why does compiler not complain about it, and can a regular developer make a thing like this ? Any ideas would be appriciated.

Comment: This is COM interop magic.